# How can I fix class model not found error when using model name via variable?

Tags: php, model, laravel-5

When I'm using this code in Laravel 5.2:

```
use 'App\modelname';

public function test()
{
    $model = 'modelname';
    $db = $model::find(1);
    echo $db->id;
}
```

it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
FatalThrowableError in HomeController.php line 541:
Class 'modelname' not found?
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked/updated the autoloader?  Are you sure it's in the proper namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
public function test()
{
    $sh = "modelname";
    $model = "App\\$sh";
    $db = $model::find(1);
    echo $db->id;
}
```